# How to make people aware of "Joomla.stackexchange.com"?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

672 days gone and we are still running in Beta.

I have seen many other users asking questions on SO but not on JSE.

It would be great if we could get those users on JSE so that we could improve **questions per day**

Is there any way to get all the Joomla related questions on JSE?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a user posts on SE, you can suggest they use JSE instead and mentione that it's a dedicated Stack Exchange site for Joomla related questions. This will ensure they are aware of JSE and will most likely use it for future questions.

If you also feel that a question does not belong on SE or will get more attention on, you can flag it and request it be migrated.

Unfortunately, voting to migrate to a different SE site, does not provide JSE an an option which is rather annoying. I think they should change the list of available SE sites to migrate to, based on the tags used in the question.

Comment: thats a good idea, thanks @Lodder and also ill post in some social media groups as well.

Comment: I have started adding the following comment to all new posts on SO which have tag 'joomla' "Hi! Not sure if you know, but there is a dedicated Joomla! community at Stackexchange. You will have a better change to get an answer if you ask your question there. http://joomla.stackexchange.com" .  The RSS feed http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=joomla&sort=newest is helping me a lot in this endeavor of trying to re-route them to JSX.

Comment: @MirkoMikan - Nice one :)

Comment: thats really awesome @MirkoMikan , thank you and Ill also start doing this :)

Comment: @Joomler Sure man... Go ahead... I just saw typo I've been doing 'chance' instead of 'change'... Whatever, it's clear enough...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there are many communications channels for Joomla users and this leads to people posting pleas for support on sites that are poorly suited to receiving support and sharing the wisdom received.

There are many ways that JSX can win:

- Get better and more questions.
- Get talented, educational, and speedier solutions.
- Get a higher volume and more frequent participation from Joomla users.

However, which comes first?  The Chicken? The Egg?

Well, you can only control your own behavior, role model good behavior, and campaign to others to have a crack -- so do ALL of it and see what happens.

How do we campaign, well, there's online and offline.  When you speak positively of the richness and warmth of JSX while attending Joomla Meetups and other IT gatherings, people will inherently want to see what all of the fuss is about.  If you are a member of any online networks (LinkedIn, Facebook, Slack, MeetUp, Google+, etc.) that speak on Joomla, never miss a chance to leave a whisper about JSX.

I openly express to the attending (and non-attending) members of the JUG Brisbane Meetup that I am happy to sit down with anyone and "hold their hand" through their first posted question/answer.  I have stood up and enthusiastically explained to our members just how great and powerful SO and JSX are as well as the myriad of career-relevant benefits to engaging in these communities.

Basically, I'll urge everyone to make scattered trails that all lead to JSX (on your business website, on your email signature, in your **LinkedIn**/**Facebook**/**Twitter**/**Slack**/**MeetUp**/**Joomla Volunteer**/**etc** profile).  Once they come here, it is again up to us to ensure that they get a positive and educational experience.  Much to do.  Be bold.

Answer (score 2):

The [Public Joomla Group on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/joomlanospam/) has 25K+ members with people asking questions all the time, many of whom I suspect are unaware of JSE.

I have often suggested for certain questions posed on the Joomla FB group that the poster might have better luck on JSE.

In particular, if a question has a good answer already on JSE then it's both helpful to the poster, and a good opportunity to promote JSE, by providing a link.