# SO Mods deleted my 'JSE comments', so I improved 'joomla' tags in return

Tags: discussion

So... this is what happened...

Between 2016-02-26 and 2016-03-17 I have posted 97 comments to the most of new Stack Overflow Qs tagged 'joomla', as my humble response to well received Q here [How to make people aware of “Joomla.stackexchange.com”?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-to-make-people-aware-of-joomla-stackexchange-com). I haven't been doing it blindly on every new post, but avoided low-quality Qs and these which someone either answered or commented in the meantime.
There were 32 response-comments of type "Thanks, I didnt know that" and I've counted 28 re-posted Qs from SO to JSE.

On 2016-03-17 @ 16:01 I received Email from SO Moderators, copy of which you can see below:

[image: 2016-03-17 SO Mods PM, Comments Deletion]

So, I went to PM link provided in the message and responded as follows:

[image: 2016-03-17 SO Mods PM, MIK Response]

They didn't respond for more than two days, so I understand that matter is closed now and I will refrain from posting any similar comment on SO in the future.
That's all I have to say about that.

BUT... as I'm not Forrest Gump, I saw only one little chance "legally" left to improve JSE Awareness on SO. I've had this idea for almost a month so I did it.

Original 'joomla' SO tag on tagged Qs listing was:

[image: stackoverflow_questions_tagged_joomla_org]

and on entering tag while asking Q was:

[image: stackoverflow_tags_joomla_org]

When I checked how Drupal and Wordpress solved similar need I saw the following:

[image: stackoverflow_questions_tagged_drupal]

and:

[image: stackoverflow_questions_tagged_wordpress]

**So I went and changed tags 'joomla' 'joomla-2.5' 'joomla-3.0' 'jomla-extensions' and 'virtuemart' as follows:**

[image: stackoverflow_questions_tagged_joomla_new]

and:

[image: stackoverflow_tags_joomla_new]

Now, that's all I have to say about that.

Comment: Seems reasonable.

Comment: Nice one. I love to have a feature where if a user is posting on SO and uses the Joomla, Wordpress, Drupal tag and there's a dedicated SE site for it, then a small alert appears telling the user know about it. I doubt very much something like this would be implemented though :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well done Mirko!

I have made similar comments without any grief from SO mods but not that many and only when I come across an unloved Joomla question on SO that has no good answers yet.

Joomla questions on SO are often closed as off-topic so it seems reasonable to me to point out that Joomla questions may be more favourably received on JSE.

I can't think of any good reason that this would upset an SO mod.

It's probably worthwhile starting a discussion on this topic on http://meta.stackoverflow.com especially as this applies to other Stack Exchange websites not just JSE.

Comment: Thanx Neil for your insights and for an idea to open discussion on this topic at SO Meta. I might do just that. I'm pretty sad because they treat us as orphans...

Comment: I'll keep posting similar comments on SO until someone tells me a valid reason not to. It's no wonder that Stack Exchange sites struggle to get out of Beta with the attitude of that particular SO mod! You have been very polite and at the very least deserve an explanation.

Comment: Great, man... And yes, I think I've been pretty polite even though I was very pissed-off because of their treatment.

Comment: @NeilRobertson - Undo is a newly elected moderator, so it's quite possible he asked the opinion of another mod that's been in the field for more time. I can understand why they don't want comments like this everywhere on SO, but also understand the fact that it makes our lives harder by trying to generate users for JSE whilst it's still in Beta :/

Comment: I don't get it. They close a lot of Joomla questions as off topic, they don't migrate questions because we're still in beta and they delete comments when someone takes the time to point out there may be a more suitable Stack Exchange website. This isn't helping anyone or am I missing something?

Comment: @NeilRobertson - I'm not a fan of every action take on here, but unfortunately it's just how it is. If you and/or Mikan expressed your opinions on Stack Exchange Meta regarding this issue and post a comment on JSE linking us to it, you'll definitely get all our upvotes. Hopefully enough to have them re-think things over :)